# Adobe illustrator shadow

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drop-shadow

Can somebody explain my why these parts have their shadows over them, while the others are completely fine. I can't even...[image: Here's the picture]

Comment: No one can possibly answer this based upon the information you've provided.

Comment: If the answer below helped you figured out what the issue was, a good way to thank the person who generously helped you is by accepting the answer by clicking on the little diamond icon next to it!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very vague. One possibility would be, that the fill opacity is set to 'Multiply' or similar, so the shape seems transparent and the shadow isn't covered up. You might want to set the fill opacity to 'Normal'.

[image: Fill Blend Mode]